# Prove that ${\rm ord}(f) = n$

Tags: polynomials

Given you have a Formal Power Series of:
$$f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$$
where the order of $f(t)$ is also denoted by ${\rm ord}(f)$.

Prove that ${\rm ord}(f)=n$ if and only if $f(0) = ··· = f^{(n−1)}(0) = 0$
and
$f^{(n)}(0) \neq 0$, where $f^{(k)}$ denotes the $k$-th derivative of $f$.

I can't seem to write comments so ill edit how far i get here: So plugging in F(0) wouldn't i be left with a0?
Then id use a basis for n=1, then assume true for n=k then plug in n=k+1, but how do i bring the f^(n-1) into it?

differentiating we'll have f'(o)=a1, f''(0)= a2... so generally f^(k)=ak?

Comment: It should be $f^{(n)}\ne0$, probably; $f(0)$ denotes the element $a_0$. The result is obvious for $n=0$; now use induction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Compute the derivatives, noting that the sums will always be finite. You will come up with equations for $a_0, \ldots, a_n$, whose solutions will be quite simple if you start with $a_0$ and go with increasing indices.